# Discord Bot Crashing In Dm

Tags: discord, discord.js

When I use certain commands in the DM's of my discord bot (e.g Mute or ServerInfo) it crashes, because it is different in DM and servers.

So, I have been searching, and the only thing I came across is from the Discord.JS guide. I tried that, but it didn't work. So, I was wondering is there any other way to make certain commands not work in DM's?

Answer (score 0):

Just return if it fails a condition which correlates to a DM channel:

```js
if(!msg.guild) return;
```

or

```js
if(msg.channel.type === "dm") return;
```

Comment: Where do i put that tho?

Comment: At the top of the code which relates to the command.